# Any way to keep Susy from changing font-size automatically?

Tags: css, fonts, susy-sass

I have been using Susy for the first time and like how simple it is, but it bothers me that it resizes font-sizes for me automatically. I would rather go through and adjust the layout with media queries, so Susy's font-size changes are a little frustrating. I have been defining my fonts in ems throughout this project- would using px make any difference? I would appreciate some guidance! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are seeing, but it's not related to Susy. Susy has no default output - so it never does anything unless you specifically request it. Susy also has no font-size tools included, so there is no way for Susy to be changing your font sizes.

Comment: A few days later, I ended up finding a few stray lines of code that were in a partial file that I wasn't using anymore. I thought it was Susy but I guess it wasn't. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Susy doesn't come with any default styles like bootstrap or foundation. A good practice is to reset all of the styling through something like Compass, they have a reset mixin. When you have a blank slate start defining variables for fonts. Here's a method I've used in projects.

```
$fontfamily: 'brandon-grotesque', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

$thin      : 200;
$normal    : 300;
$mid       : 500;
$bold      : 600;
$heavy     : 800;

$headFont  : $thin 1.5em/1.5em $fontfamily;
$mainFont  : $mid 1em/1.5em $fontfamily;
```

Then declare them in you sass:

```
body {
  font: $mainFont;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to do a little more reading about fonts defined in fractions like that. I've seen it done before but haven't done it myself.